# Can you tell me from where it comes discount in Magento 2 order items

Tags: magento2, discount

I see it show discount in Magento 2 admin order details page . But I am unable to find out the reason of discount . There is no catalog price rule applied. Can anyone give me idea how i can find out that ?

Please look image I attach so you can understood .[image: Not sure from where idscount comes]

Comment: have you checked in cart price rule ?

Comment: Your screenshot doesnt make any sense as if it had discounted it would of been shown in the order totals it has charged the correct amount in the subtotal but it has no discount total which is very strange. do you have any 3rd party extensions installation on your website

Answer (score 2):

can you check applied_rule ids into db for that order, by using you get more info

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems cart item rules apply here without coupon code.You can confirm it by checking all cart rule from `Admin->Marketing->cart price rules.`

Check all cart rules and sure you have not any rules.

Since it cut half price hence may be any rules applied before and it is deleted now.

You can reorder same product by disabling all cart price rules for some time and that will confirm you.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I had deleted cart rules after applied on order. I have tried another order with same cart items and it is working fine to me.

Please clear all the cache after disabling or clearing cart rule.